# How do I set map zoom based on nearest pin to current location

Tags: iphone, ios

Right now I am setting my region based on users current location.  I would like to now set the zoom level so I can see the users current location and the nearest pin that is being pulled in via json.

Not until run time will the app know the number of pins or the locations of said pins.

Here is what I have so far.

```
@implementation LocationsViewController

@synthesize mapView;
@synthesize locationManager;
@synthesize phone;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) 
    {
        self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Locations", @"Locations");
        self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"locations"];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

 #pragma mark - View lifecycle

 //Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    NSLog(@"New latitude: %f", newLocation.coordinate.latitude);
    NSLog(@"New longitude: %f", newLocation.coordinate.longitude);

    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    region.center.latitude =newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
    region.center.longitude=  newLocation.coordinate.longitude;
    region.span.longitudeDelta=0.2;
    region.span.latitudeDelta =0.2;
    [mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
    [mapView setDelegate:self];
    //[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

}

-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];   
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated 
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    if([self connectedToNetwork] != YES)
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"OH NO!" message:@"To get the latest information you need a data or wi-fi connection" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }
    else
    {
        [mapView removeAnnotations:mapView.annotations];

        NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.mywebsite.com/json.json"];

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

        NSError *error;

        NSMutableDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

        for(id key in json) {
            id value = [json objectForKey:key];
            NSString *titlePin = [value valueForKey:@"address"];
            NSString *address = [value valueForKey:@"title"];
            NSString *latitude = [value valueForKey:@"latitude"];
            NSString *longitude = [value valueForKey:@"longitude"];

            NSArray* foo = [address componentsSeparatedByString: @":"];
            NSString* address2 = [foo objectAtIndex: 0];
            phone = [foo objectAtIndex: 1];

            double myLatitude = [latitude doubleValue];
            double myLongitude = [longitude doubleValue];

            MKCoordinateRegion location1;
            location1.center.latitude =myLatitude;
            location1.center.longitude= myLongitude;
            location1.span.longitudeDelta=0.1;
            location1.span.latitudeDelta =0.1;

            MapAnnotation *ann1 =[[[MapAnnotation alloc] init] autorelease];
            ann1.title=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",titlePin];
            ann1.subtitle=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",address2];
            ann1.phone=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",phone];
            ann1.coordinate= location1.center;
            [mapView addAnnotation:ann1];
            [phone retain];

        }
     }
}

-(MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView2 viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    if (annotation == mapView2.userLocation) {
        return nil;
    }else{
         MKPinAnnotationView *MyPin=[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"current"];
        MyPin.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;

        UIButton *advertButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoDark];
         [advertButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mapphone"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
         [advertButton addTarget:self action:@selector(button:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
         MyPin.rightCalloutAccessoryView = advertButton;


        MyPin.draggable = NO;
        MyPin.highlighted = YES;
        MyPin.animatesDrop=TRUE;
        MyPin.canShowCallout = YES;

        return MyPin;
     }
 }

 -(void)button:(id)sender {

     UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;

     MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKPinAnnotationView*)button.superview.superview;

     MapAnnotation *mapAnnotation = annotationView.annotation;

     UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
     if ([[device model] isEqualToString:@"iPhone"] ) {
         [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@",mapAnnotation.phone]]];
     } else {
         UIAlertView *Notpermitted=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:mapAnnotation.phone message:@"Your device doesn't support this feature." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
         [Notpermitted show];
         [Notpermitted release];
    }

}

 - (BOOL) connectedToNetwork
 {  
    Reachability *r = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"www.google.com"];
    NetworkStatus internetStatus = [r currentReachabilityStatus];
    BOOL internet;
    if ((internetStatus != ReachableViaWiFi) && (internetStatus != ReachableViaWWAN)) {
        internet = NO;
    } else {
        internet = YES;
    }
    return internet;
} 

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return YES;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar, but based on two annotations, not the user's location. You should be able to replace mapView.centerCoordinate with mapView.userLocation.coordinate.

in viewForAnnotation:

```
   CLLocation *centerLoc = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:mapView.centerCoordinate.latitude longitude:mapView.centerCoordinate.longitude];
   CLLocation *loc2 = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[annotation coordinate].latitude longitude:[annotation coordinate].longitude];
   CLLocationDistance distance = [loc2 distanceFromLocation:centerLoc];

   MKCoordinateRegion viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(mapView.centerCoordinate, distance*2, distance*2);
   MKCoordinateRegion adjustedRegion = [mapView regionThatFits:viewRegion];
   [mapView setRegion:adjustedRegion animated:YES];
```

Note, this code will re-calc the zoom level each time you add an annotation. You may need to save the distance and only change the map if the new distance is greater than the prior distance.